# Optimal way to check if given sentence(query) contains any of the predefined keywords

Tags: mysql, mongodb, elasticsearch, amazon-dynamodb, couchbase

It might look like a simple question already answered countless times, but I could not find the optimal way(using some db).

I have a list of few thousands keywords(let's say abusive words). Whenever someone posts a message(long sentence or a paragraph), I want to check if the given sentence contains any of the keywords, so that I can block user or take other actions.

I am looking for a db/schema which can solve the above problem and gives response in a few milliseconds(<15ms).

There are many dbs which solves the reverse of the above problem: given the keywords, find documents containing keywords(text search).

Comment: Given it's just a few thousand words, I would cache them in-memory and do the check there, and periodically refetch the list of words from the database using a standard query.

Comment: I agree, an in memory dictionary should do that job if its just few 1000 words.

Comment: I agree. But here we will be having 1-10k keywords for each account. Number of accounts will also be in the range of few thousands.

Answer (score 2):

Try [ClickHouse](https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse) for your workload.

According to docs:

> [multiMatchAny(...)](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/query_language/functions/string_search_functions/#multimatchany-haystack-pattern1-pattern2-patternn) returns 0 if none of the regular expressions are matched and 1 if any of the patterns matches. It uses [hyperscan](https://www.hyperscan.io/) library. For patterns to search substrings in a string, it is better to use multiSearchAny since it works much faster.
>   The length of any of the haystack string must be less than 2^32 bytes.

Comment: Thanks. looks good, have to explore more about it.